# Extracting source code of System.net.http VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, dotnet-httpclient, decompiling, decompiler

I manage to step into non user code to see how httpClient behaves.
I manage to see source code of some classes, but not all, for example : HttpClientHandler seems inaccessible
If I try to step into:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = _handler.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

it does not go into SendAsync, and I do not see the source code in the miscalenous files in the solution (while I see some others)
[image: debugging snapshot]

one strange thing is that i see in properties in extracted source code that they are in different  directories (hash of the same pdb seems different):
[image: different paths]

I cannot either navigate to the definition with F12

Comment: may be this can guide you on debugging with source link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/

Comment: Could you provide some more specific code and steps to reproduce the issue?